# [LibreOffice Writer]: How to create empty line space after every period in a paragraph in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

How to create empty line space after every period in a paragraph in LibreOffice Writer as like below:

**Original Paragraph:**

aaaaaa.bbbbb.cccccc.ddddddd.

**Expected Paragraph:**

aaaaaa.

bbbbb.

cccccc.

ddddddd.

If it is possible as per my expectation using LibreOffice Writer means guide me to get the above output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position your cursor at the start of the paragraph in question. Then in the **Find & Replace dialog**...

- Check `Regular expressions` under "Other options"
- Set **Find:** to `\.`
- Set **Replace:** to `&\n\n`
- Click the "Replace" button repeatedly until the paragraph changes are complete (Note that the first click will likely just position the cursor at the first '.')

For the whole document, do the same except position your cursor at the start of the document and click the "Replace All" button rather than "Replace".

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I expect. Thank you very much for your valuable response.